# Clustering the Batch Job & distributing the data load

Tags: cluster-computing

I have Batch Processing project, wanted to cluster on 5 machines.
Suppose I have input source is database having 1000 records.
I want to split these records equally i.e. 200 records/instance of batch job.

How could we distribute the work load ?

Comment: Instance-1 : Records 1 to 200,  Instance-2 : Records 201 to 400, Instance-3 : Records 401 to 600, Instance-4 : Records 601 to 800, Instance-5 : Records 801 to 1000                                                                     The number of records could be vary. This is a sample.

Comment: Are you looking to execute 200 records in 5 machines in a  parallel manner?

Comment: Yes...I want to execute it in parallel

Answer (score 0):

Given below, is the workflow that you may want to follow.

**Assumptions:**

1. You have the necessary Domain Objects respective to the DB table.
2. You have a batch flow configured wherein, there is a
   reader/writer/tasklet mechanism.
3. You have a Messaging System (Messaging Queues are a great way to
   make distributed applications talk to each other)
4. Input object is an object to the queue that contains the set of
   input records split as per the required size.
5. Result object is an object to the queue that contains the processed
   records or result value(if scalar)
6. The chunkSize is configured in a property file. Here 200

**Design:**
*In the application,*

1. Configure a queueReader to read from a queue
2. Configure a queueWriter to write to a queue
3. If using the task/tasklet mechanism, configure different queues to carry the input/result objects.
4. Configure a DB reader which reads from a DB

*Logic in the DBReader*

5. Read records from DB one by one and count of records maintained. if
   (count%chunkSize==0) then write all the records to the inputMessage
   object and write the object to the queue.

*Logic in queueReader*

6. Read the messages one by one
7. For each present message do the necessary processing.
8. Create a resultObject

*Logic in the queueWriter*

9. Read the resultObject (usually batch frameworks provide a way to
   ensure that writers are able to read the output from readers)
10. If any applicable processing or downstream interaction is needed,
     add it here.
11. Write the result object to the outputQueue.

**Deployment**

Package once, deploy multiple instances. For better performance, ensure that the chunkSize is small to enable fast processing. The queues are managed by the messaging system (The available systems in the market provide ways to monitor the queues) where you will be able to see the message flow.

Comment: But here the source of Input is not fixed....it could be anything e.g. 1000, 1567, 3002, 4097 etc. So How we could distribute it to each clustered instance equally ?

Comment: For a dynamic input, the equal distribution can be done in two ways. 1) You get the record count from the dbReader, and in the first step split into 5 parts. 2) Considering that source is not fixed, you may need to create multiple 'streams' of messages and split into each part. Take a small number of records (say n=100) and for every n records pass it to a different queue. Once all the 5 instance queues are populated, repeat from instance 1. This method enables splitting and processing with efficiency. for larger values of n, the message processing may take more time

Comment: Thanks Amal for your reply. With Addition to your answer one more query here. Suppose now there are 4 clustered instances & due to some issues one instance is down or in case of addition of one more cluster instance. i.e. instances count are not fixed. How the load will get distribute dynamically ?

Comment: You might need to work on a separate service that does the health check of the servers. The primary responsibility will be to poll the cluster instances at fixed intervals and get a response of the ISAlive status. The count should be updated by this service in such scenarios. Also, introduction of such a service will mean that your design considers HA as an important factor. But HA is out of scope of this answer here. Plenty of links available on the net and StackOverflow for that.

Comment: @SUKHDEVPATIL If it has solved your problem, please mark the post as answered